# Multiply two field values

Tags: jquery

I have two form fields, field 1 is a select menu with different packages and prices, field 2 is the amount you want. Now I found some code that takes the value from field 1 and field 2 and adds them up and finally shows the sum.

I want to change this to take the value from field 1 and multiply it with the value from field 2, how do I do this ?

Here's the code: ("sv_313" is the package, "amountk" is the value to multiply it with)

```
$(function() {
    $('#sv_313').on('change', function() {
        calculate();
    });

    $('input[name=amountk]').on('blur', function() {
        calculate();
    });
});

function calculate() {
    var $select = $('#sv_313').val();
    var $text = $('input[name=amountk]').val();

    if ($select == undefined || $select == '' ||$select == 'Select One') {
        $select = 0;
    }
    else {
        $select = parseFloat($select);
    }
    //
    if ($text == undefined || $text == '') {
        $text = 0;
    }
    else {
        $text = parseFloat($text);
    }

    $('.coverage').html($select + $text);
}
```

Comment: Why are you using `$select + $text` if you want to multiply the two variables?

Comment: Yes that was indeed the problem as Venu pointed out. Thank you too.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can use

```
$('.coverage').html($select * $text);
```

Comment: Can't believe I missed that, thank you ! Will accept answer when I can.